# Having trouble increasing item quantity when multiple of the same item are added to very simple cart element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Ok hello, so I am trying to increment the quantity of each item added to the cart, if the item has already been added. This is also my first post so if you have tips on how to better frame further questions, much appreciated. (I did look for related questions and searched through various resources but could not find exactly what I need for my certain issue)

I made the condition to check if the quantity is less than 10, so that it would hopefully increment to 10 just to see if that would work. However, it only increments to 2. it logs the array to the console and it shows that the item has a quantity: 1 once clicked and does increase to quantity: 2 if clicked a second time. It does not go beyond that though, i can click if 4, 5 times and it is always as quantity: 2. not sure how to fix this?

```
handleClick = (product) => {
    product['quantity'] = 1;
    let sameItem = this.state.cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id == product.id);
    console.log(sameItem);
    if(sameItem != -1){
      if(this.state.cartItems[sameItem].quantity < 10){
        this.state.cartItems[sameItem].quantity += 1;
      }
    } else {
      let cartItems = [...this.state.cartItems, product];
      this.setState({ cartItems }, () => console.log(this.state.cartItems));
    }
    console.log(this.state.cartItems);


  }

 {/* This is all im trying to display with the cart for now, but it does not increment, but even in the console it does not increment */}
        <div>
          {cartItems.map(item => (
            <p key={item.id} >{item.quantity}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
```

I am expecting for the console.log of the this.state.cartItems to increment the quantity field each time the item is clicked, as well as the displayed quantity in the cart element in the return() of the react component.

Comment: You forgot to setState in if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to collect the updated cartItems and then setState by the updated one:

```js
if(this.state.cartItems[sameItem].quantity < 10){

    let newCartItems = this.state.cartItems.map( (item,index)=>{
        if (index == sameItem) {
          item.quntity +=1;
          return item
        } else {
          return item;
        }
    });
    
    this.setState({cartItems:newCartItems});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to setState in if block

```
if(this.state.cartItems[sameItem].quantity < 10){
    this.state.cartItems[sameItem].quantity += 1;
    this.setState({cartItems});
 }
```